# Zip file isn't created and not downloaded from temp directory outside public_html

Tags: php

I have a simple script that should create and download the zip files from the files in the directory.

For some reason, the file isn't created/downloaded and will need your expertise. This is the script.

```
$i=0;
while ($stmt->fetch()) 
{
    $dir = '../tmp/file-'.$nom.'.pdf';
    $file_names[] = str_replace('../tmp/', '', $dir);
    $i++;
}
$stmt->close();

if (!empty($dir))
{
        
    $archive_file_name = '../tmp/files.zip';
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    
    if ($zip->open($archive_file_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE )!==TRUE) {
        exit("cannot open <$archive_file_name>\n");
    }
            
    foreach($file_names as $files)
    {
        $zip->addFile($files, basename($files));
    }
    $zip->close();
    ob_clean();
        
    if (file_exists($archive_file_name)) {          
        header("Content-type: application/zip"); 
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$archive_file_name);
        header("Content-length: " . filesize($archive_file_name));
        header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
        header("Expires: 0"); 
        readfile("$archive_file_name");

    } else {
        exit("Could not find Zip file to download");
    }           
}
```

Always got the `Could not find Zip file to download`.

The script is in

```
 /site.com/admin/script.php
```

the temp dir is

```
/tmp/`
```

both are outside the `public_html`. `/tmp` and `/site.com` are on same level

Comment: Are you sure the ZIP file contains any files? Because in [close()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.close.php) it says: _"If the archive contains no files, the file is completely removed (no empty archive is written)."_.

Comment: Well, I'm sure that `file_names[]` contains 58 names which are files in `/tmp`. I'm not sure if they are actually added to the zip.

Comment: OK, so then you need to check the return value of [addFile()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php).

Comment: Or use [count()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.count.php). Even better, use both.

Comment: But the problem here is that apparently, the file doesn't exist. ..or I probably don't understand what you mean

Comment: What I mean is: If, for some reason, the files are not added to the ZIP file, and it therefore contains zero files, the ZIP archive itself will not exist.

Comment: I get that. But this won't tell me why the file isn't created, right?

Comment: If by _"the file"_ you mean the ZIP archive, then yes, if no files are added to the archive, in other words `$zip->count()` is zero when you call `$zip->close()`, the archive will not be created.

Comment: Yes, and that's why I posted the question. I know that there are files for sure. I don't know why they aren't added to the zip archive and asked here if someone can see something in my code that I missed it.

Comment: OK, I'll add an answer with the code that will check if files are added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code looks like this.

```
foreach($file_names as $files)
{
    $zip->addFile($files, basename($files));
}
$zip->close();
```

If you want to check if your files are really added you can do this:

```
foreach($file_names as $path)
{
    if (!file_exists($path))
    {
        exit("File [$path] does not exist.";
    }
    if ($zip->addFile($path, basename($path)) === false) 
    {
        exit("File [$path] could not be added to the ZIP file" .
             ", the reason is: " . $zip->getStatusString());
    }
}
if ($zip->count() == 0) 
{
    exit("No files were added to the ZIP file");
}
$zip->close();
```

Comment: Or for a service where you want to silently ignore errors, there should still be some similar code that can be turned on for debugging use  - if debug do the above, else silently exit

Comment: Thanks, @KIKO. Got the error `File [file-3000001531.pdf] could not be added to the ZIP file`. Now I'm wondering why since they are all same

Comment: @DaveS Yes, a lot of improvements can be made. Please read the comments below the question. This is just example code in the same style as the question.

Comment: @Jake: To know why this happens there is the [getStatusString()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.getstatusstring.php) method. I'll add it to this answer.

Comment: Because no error: `File [file-3000000624.pdf] could not be added to the ZIP file, the reason is: No error`

Comment: Well, that's not very informative, isn't it? You can also check if the file exists before you add it to the ZIP archive with [file_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists). I'll add that too.

Comment: So, `File [file-3000000624.pdf] does not exist.`... meaning doesn't reach the directory because I've checked and the file is there.

Comment: @Jake Yes, it's probably a simple problem of getting the paths to the files correct.

Comment: Thanks again. Will mark the answer and will continue to check why this happen.